# How to auto select the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an HTML table, inside which I have several input fields, so when I select any option from the `dropdown` I am populating one row of the table, inside that row `itemname` as input field which is `autocomplete`.

So what I am doing is I have a string like `A BR SB EX~333` where 333 is the item code and other is a name, so when I type 333 that item gets populated. Then on pressing enter I am focusing out and doing some calculations.

**What I am trying to do**

- When I type for instance `333` in autocomplete field and only one option is there I want to populate that inside my `inputfield`. I don't want the user to manually select that option, just type if that matched to a single `name`, then on pressing enter populate that inside the input field.

**My code**

```js
var tableData = {
  "ALMOND CHBAR~2402": {
    "itemName": "ALMOND CHBAR",
    "itemCode": "2402",
    "costPrice": 20.0,
    "gstPercentage": 14.5,
    "mrp": 30.0
  },
  "A BR SB EX~333": {
    "itemName": "A BR SB EX",
    "itemCode": "333",
    "costPrice": 1.0,
    "gstPercentage": 0.0,
    "mrp": 1.0
  }
}


var autoCompleteData = Object.keys(tableData);

function rowappend(tbody) {

  const markup =
    `<tr>
           <td>
             <input type="text" class="form-control commanChange" id="itemNametd" name="itemNametd">
           </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="itemCodetd" id="itemCodetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="mrptd" id="mrptd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="purRatetd" id="purRatetd" class="form-control commantd"></td>
           <td>
             <input type="tel" id="unitQtytd"class="form-control commanChange" name="unitQtytd">
           </td>
                         
           <td>
             <input type="tel" id="discPercentagetd"class="form-control commanChange" name="discPercentagetd" >
           </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="discAmttd" id="discAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td> 
           <td><input type="text" name="gstPercentagetd" id="gstPercentagetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="gstAmttd" id="gstAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="totalAmttd" id="totalAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td style="background-color: white;border: 1px white"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x remove-btn"></i></td>
           
         </tr>`

  $(tbody).append(markup);
  setTimeout(() => $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().focus(), 100);

  $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().autocomplete({
    source: autoCompleteData

  });




}
rowappend($('tbody', '#tableInvoice'))

function getValues(row) {

  const search = ($('[name=itemNametd]', row).val()).toString()
  const value = tableData[search];
  CostPrice = value.costPrice;

  if (value) {
    $(row).find("[name=itemCodetd]").val(value.itemCode);
    $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val(value.mrp);
    $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val(CostPrice);

    $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val(value.gstPercentage);
  }

}
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
  if (event.target.matches('[name=itemNametd]')) {

    var keycode = e.keyCode || event.e;
    if (keycode == '13') {

      getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
      $("[name=purRatetd]").focus();

    }
  }

});
$(document).on('focusout', (e) => {

  const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
  if (e.target.matches("[name=itemNametd]")) {


    getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
    $("[name=purRatetd]").focus();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row tableInvoice" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
        <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">Item Code</th>
        <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
        <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Pur.Rate</th>
        <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc%</th>
        <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
        <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">Gst%</th>
        <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">Gst Amt</th>
        <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

[image: please check out this image for better understanding]

When I type and there is only one item left as option I want that to come inside the input field so that the user does not select it manually.

If there is any other way to do this autocomplete I am open to use that, I just want so that while I am typing I should get the input field filled as I don't want to select it manually.

Comment: Check out https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-autoFocus

Comment: @mkane yes I just found that

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found Something in `j query` autocomplete plug i.e

```
autoSelectFirst: true,
 autoFocus: true
```

this is doing what I am trying to achieve

```js
var tableData = {
  "ALMOND CHBAR~2402": {
    "itemName": "ALMOND CHBAR",
    "itemCode": "2402",
    "costPrice": 20.0,
    "gstPercentage": 14.5,
    "mrp": 30.0
  },
  "A BR SB EX~333": {
    "itemName": "A BR SB EX",
    "itemCode": "333",
    "costPrice": 1.0,
    "gstPercentage": 0.0,
    "mrp": 1.0
  }
}


var autoCompleteData = Object.keys(tableData);

function rowappend(tbody) {

  const markup =
    `<tr>
           <td>
             <input type="text" class="form-control commanChange" id="itemNametd" name="itemNametd">
           </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="itemCodetd" id="itemCodetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="mrptd" id="mrptd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="purRatetd" id="purRatetd" class="form-control commantd"></td>
           <td>
             <input type="tel" id="unitQtytd"class="form-control commanChange" name="unitQtytd">
           </td>
                         
           <td>
             <input type="tel" id="discPercentagetd"class="form-control commanChange" name="discPercentagetd" >
           </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="discAmttd" id="discAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td> 
           <td><input type="text" name="gstPercentagetd" id="gstPercentagetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="gstAmttd" id="gstAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="totalAmttd" id="totalAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td style="background-color: white;border: 1px white"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x remove-btn"></i></td>
           
         </tr>`

  $(tbody).append(markup);
  setTimeout(() => $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().focus(), 100);

  $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().autocomplete({
    source: autoCompleteData,
    autoSelectFirst: true,
    autoFocus: true

  });




}
rowappend($('tbody', '#tableInvoice'))

function getValues(row) {

  const search = ($('[name=itemNametd]', row).val()).toString()
  const value = tableData[search];
  CostPrice = value.costPrice;

  if (value) {
    $(row).find("[name=itemCodetd]").val(value.itemCode);
    $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val(value.mrp);
    $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val(CostPrice);

    $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val(value.gstPercentage);
  }

}
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
  if (event.target.matches('[name=itemNametd]')) {

    var keycode = e.keyCode || event.e;
    if (keycode == '13') {

      getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
      $("[name=purRatetd]").focus();

    }
  }

});
$(document).on('focusout', (e) => {

  const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
  if (e.target.matches("[name=itemNametd]")) {


    getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
    $("[name=purRatetd]").focus();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row tableInvoice" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
        <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">Item Code</th>
        <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
        <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Pur.Rate</th>
        <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc%</th>
        <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
        <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">Gst%</th>
        <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">Gst Amt</th>
        <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

i am posting this answer, but I am ready to use other approaches also

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, you need to use `response` callback for that

```js
var tableData = {
  "ALMOND CHBAR~2402": {
    "itemName": "ALMOND CHBAR",
    "itemCode": "2402",
    "costPrice": 20.0,
    "gstPercentage": 14.5,
    "mrp": 30.0
  },
  "A BR SB EX~333": {
    "itemName": "A BR SB EX",
    "itemCode": "333",
    "costPrice": 1.0,
    "gstPercentage": 0.0,
    "mrp": 1.0
  }
}


var autoCompleteData = Object.keys(tableData);

function rowappend(tbody) {

  const markup =
    `<tr>
           <td>
             <input type="text" class="form-control commanChange" id="itemNametd" name="itemNametd">
           </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="itemCodetd" id="itemCodetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="mrptd" id="mrptd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="purRatetd" id="purRatetd" class="form-control commantd"></td>
           <td>
             <input type="tel" id="unitQtytd"class="form-control commanChange" name="unitQtytd">
           </td>
                         
           <td>
             <input type="tel" id="discPercentagetd"class="form-control commanChange" name="discPercentagetd" >
           </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="discAmttd" id="discAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td> 
           <td><input type="text" name="gstPercentagetd" id="gstPercentagetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="gstAmttd" id="gstAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="totalAmttd" id="totalAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
           <td style="background-color: white;border: 1px white"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x remove-btn"></i></td>
           
         </tr>`

  $(tbody).append(markup);
  setTimeout(() => $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().focus(), 100);

  $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().autocomplete({
    source: autoCompleteData,
    response: (e, ui)=>{
      if(ui.content.length === 1){
        $(e.target).val(ui.content[0].label);
        $(e.target).autocomplete( "close" );
      }
    }
  });




}
rowappend($('tbody', '#tableInvoice'))

function getValues(row) {

  const search = ($('[name=itemNametd]', row).val()).toString()
  const value = tableData[search];
  CostPrice = value.costPrice;

  if (value) {
    $(row).find("[name=itemCodetd]").val(value.itemCode);
    $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val(value.mrp);
    $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val(CostPrice);

    $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val(value.gstPercentage);
  }

}
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
  if (event.target.matches('[name=itemNametd]')) {

    var keycode = e.keyCode || event.e;
    if (keycode == '13') {

      getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
      $("[name=purRatetd]").focus();

    }
  }

});
$(document).on('focusout', (e) => {

  const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
  if (e.target.matches("[name=itemNametd]")) {


    getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
    $("[name=purRatetd]").focus();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row tableInvoice" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
        <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">Item Code</th>
        <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
        <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Pur.Rate</th>
        <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc%</th>
        <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
        <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">Gst%</th>
        <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">Gst Amt</th>
        <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: hey I have found that with `j query` plugin I think that would be perfect

Comment: yup your approach is also working, but using the above one I think will be perfect for my work

Comment: if you think that your approach solves your problem, then use your approach otherwise I've provided you the best solution without any additional plugin or library

Comment: Yup thanks for that, I will up-vote your answer for that